# Annoying counter strike 1.6 auto-connect - no solution worked for me

Tags: counter-strike

We all know the "auto connect" annoying 'hacks' on the Counter-Strike configuration files.

So basically this problem is similar to the other problems; everytime I connect a server, it connects to the same server. But, the weird thing is, that it happens when I am trying to connect a server that is in my *Favorites* list, for example. It doesn't happen when I click on the *New Game* or *Find Servers* buttons. Only when I'm trying to connect a new server.

I tried couple things in order to solve this annoying problem:

- Connecting through the console (~) with the `connect [IP]` command.
- Deleting my `GameMenu.res`. Deleting my CS (`cstrike`) folder.
- I even reinstalled Counter-Strike, but this still occurs.
- My CS folder is *Read-Only*. So are my `config.cfg`, `userconfig.cfg`, etc.

I am playing through Steam, of course.

This is what my console looks like:

[image: console screenshot]

It always connects to `king.indungi.ro:27015`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fav servers are not saved inside cstrike, that's why it still can be modified by hacks and other tools (including Steam itself, when saving a new server).

Check the file `...\Steam\userdata\(id number)\7\remote\serverbrowser_hist.vdf`

`(id number)` references a unique account ID. If you have used multiple Steam IDs on your computer you'll have to look through them to find the right folder. This can be done by checking `...\Steam\userdata\(id number)\config\localconfig.vdf`, which should contain the Steam account name.

PS: It's always good to have a backup of that folder, because the Steam cloud is not very reliable and some hacking tools tend to modify or delete more than just your server list.

Comment: Checked, even though nothing was suspicious, I deleted it. Nothing changed.

Comment: (Sorry for double posts) But what's really weird is that: it does the auto connect only on specific servers. I mean, I entered into other server and it didn't auto connect. Isn't it weird?

Comment: @rolory if you save a new server, does that one work as intended? (and does it appear in the file I posted in the answer?)